# jQuery: validating doesn't work before trying to submit

Tags: jquery, validation

i have this code below to validate a required field:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gestione_profilo").validate({
    rules: {
                    'person_data[document_number]': "required"
    }
    });
```

When I show the form and remove the value of that field, it doesn't show the "Required" message. But after trying to submit the form without the value inserted, it shows the "Required" message correctly each time the field is empty.

Any idea why it doesn't work before trying to sumbit the form?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#homepage_enquiry :input.required').blur(function(){}).valid();
```

This will also work but only after they have tried to input something.  The blur function works when they move away from the input box I think.  I preferred it as I didn't want it showing errors before the input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use keyup function here:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    ...validate form here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery ready function is evaluated only once, when the html DOM is ready; just like javascript onload etc. I think what you need to implement is jquery .change() event, so the validation rule is checked every time the field is changed...

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to trigger validation off the bat, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gestione_profilo").validate({
        rules: {
            'person_data[document_number]': "required"
        }
    });
    $("#gestione_profilo").valid();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PebkJ/).